# Is it possible to make a reverse tunnel using MOSH?

Tags: reverse-tunnel

on My PC:

```
mosh --ssh="ssh -R 1024:localhost:22" root@RaspberryPi
```

on Pi:

```
ssh -p 1024 root@localhost
```

But I got this message:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ssh -p 1024 root@localhost
socket: Address family not supported by protocol
ssh: connect to host localhost port 1024: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Is it possible to make a reverse tunnel using MOSH? or where am I wrong?

**update:**

on Pi:

```
mosh --ssh="ssh -R 1024:localhost:22" root@PC
```

on PC:

```
ssh -p 1024 root@localhost
```

then I was refused:

```
bash-3.2$ ssh -p 1024 pi@192.168.1.222
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.222 port 1024: Connection refused
```

As the title said , how can I make a reverse tunnel using MOSH? Is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

The `--ssh` command given to mosh is used only to launch the `mosh-server` remotely. The SSH connection is immediately closed afterwards, so you cannot set up any tunnels this way. (On top of that, the mosh SSP protocol does *not* support transferring arbitrary data; a separate tool is planned for that.)

However, the error message on your rπ is not caused by that. The `socket()` function returns EAFNOSUPPORT when the program tries to use a protocol that the OS does not support. My guess is that `ssh` is trying to use IPv6 but you have disabled it system-wide.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I misunderstood the --ssh option.